# Depth stencil buffer not working directx11

Tags: directx, buffer, direct3d, depth

ok i tried everything at this point and I'm really lost....

```
ID3D11Texture2D* depthStencilTexture;

D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC depthTexDesc;
ZeroMemory (&depthTexDesc, sizeof(D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC));
depthTexDesc.Width = set->mapSettings["SCREEN_WIDTH"];
depthTexDesc.Height = set->mapSettings["SCREEN_HEIGHT"];
depthTexDesc.MipLevels = 1;
depthTexDesc.ArraySize = 1;
depthTexDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT;
depthTexDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
depthTexDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
depthTexDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
depthTexDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
depthTexDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE | D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
depthTexDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

mDevice->CreateTexture2D(&depthTexDesc, NULL, &depthStencilTexture);

D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC dsDesc;
// Depth test parameters
dsDesc.DepthEnable = true;
dsDesc.DepthWriteMask = D3D11_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ALL;
dsDesc.DepthFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS;//LESS

// Stencil test parameters
dsDesc.StencilEnable = false;
dsDesc.StencilReadMask = 0xFF;
dsDesc.StencilWriteMask = 0xFF;

// Stencil operations if pixel is front-facing
dsDesc.FrontFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP; //KEEP
dsDesc.FrontFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_INCR; //INCR
dsDesc.FrontFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP; //KEEP
dsDesc.FrontFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

// Stencil operations if pixel is back-facing
dsDesc.BackFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP; //KEEP
dsDesc.BackFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_DECR; //DECR
dsDesc.BackFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP; //KEEP
dsDesc.BackFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

// Create depth stencil state
mDevice->CreateDepthStencilState(&dsDesc, &mDepthStencilState);

D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC depthStencilViewDesc;
ZeroMemory (&depthStencilViewDesc, sizeof(depthStencilViewDesc));
depthStencilViewDesc.Format = depthTexDesc.Format;
depthStencilViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
depthStencilViewDesc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;

mDevice->CreateDepthStencilView(depthStencilTexture, &depthStencilViewDesc, &mDepthStencilView);

mDeviceContext->OMSetDepthStencilState(mDepthStencilState, 1);
```

and then afterwards i call

```
mDeviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &mTargetView, mDepthStencilView);
```

obviously i clean before every frame

```
mDeviceContext->ClearRenderTargetView(mTargetView, D3DXCOLOR(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
mDeviceContext->ClearDepthStencilView(mDepthStencilView, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH, 1.0f, 0 );
```

and still it just keeps the last pixel drawn with no testing....

[screenshot](http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/1581/ofap.png)

PS i've checked the rasterizer and it is correctly drawing only the front faces

any help anyone?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?  You've set the stencil buffer to always pass ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your HRESULTs - the call to CreateTexture2D is almost certainly failing because you have specified CPU_ACCESS flags on a DEFAULT texture.  Since you never check any errors or pointers, this just propagates NULL to all your depth objects, effectively disabling depth testing.

You can also catch errors like this by enabling D3D debug layers, by adding D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG to the flags on D3D11CreateDevice.  If you had done this, you would see the following debug spew:

> D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::CreateTexture2D: A D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT
>   Resource cannot have any CPUAccessFlags set. The following
>   CPUAccessFlags bits cannot be set in this case: D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ
>   (1), D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE (1). [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #98:
>   CREATETEXTURE2D_INVALIDCPUACCESSFLAGS]